# Merge 3 Tables into 1 SpringBoot + Postgres

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have an Application written in spring boot with 3 Tables T1, T2 and T3 on Postgres

t1 one2many mapping with t2 and t2 one2many with t3

How can I merge these tables into one? Do the model and repository still stay the same?

Model for T1

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "maintenance_type")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdAt", "updatedAt" }, allowGetters = true)
public class MaintenanceType implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@Column(unique=true)
private String changeType;

@Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreatedDate
private Date createdAt;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@LastModifiedDate
private Date updatedAt;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "maintenanceType", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<TierTwoQuestion> tierTwoQuestion;

public MaintenanceType() {
}


public MaintenanceType(Long id, String changeType) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.changeType = changeType;
}


public MaintenanceType(String changeType) {
    super();
    this.changeType = changeType;
}


public Set<TierTwoQuestion> getTierTwoQuestion() {
    return tierTwoQuestion;
}

//
public void setTierTwoQuestion(Set<TierTwoQuestion> tierTwoQuestion) {
    this.tierTwoQuestion = tierTwoQuestion;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getChangeType() {
    return changeType;
}

public void setChangeType(String changeType) {
    this.changeType = changeType;
}

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public Date getUpdatedAt() {
    return updatedAt;
}

public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
    this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
}
}
```

Model for T2

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tier_two_question")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdAt", "updatedAt" }, allowGetters = true)
public class TierTwoQuestion implements Serializable {
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String question;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "maintenanceId", nullable = false)
    private MaintenanceType maintenanceType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tierTwoQuestion", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TierThreeQuestion> tierThreeQuestion;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updatedAt;

    public TierTwoQuestion() {
    }


    public TierTwoQuestion(Long id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.question = question;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getUpdatedAt() {
        return updatedAt;
    }

    public void setUpdatedAt(Date updatedAt) {
        this.updatedAt = updatedAt;
    }

    // public MaintenanceType getMaintenanceType() {
    // return maintenanceType;
    // }

    public void setMaintenanceType(MaintenanceType maintenanceType) {
        this.maintenanceType = maintenanceType;
    }

    public Set<TierThreeQuestion> getTierThreeQuestion() {
        return tierThreeQuestion;
    }

    public void setTierThreeQuestion(Set<TierThreeQuestion> tierThreeQuestion) {
        this.tierThreeQuestion = tierThreeQuestion;
    }

}
```

I tried adding recreating the model with all T1 T2 T3 in one table but not working as expected

Comment: You can create named query for that.

Comment: Like this : select p from MaintenanceType m
left fetch join m.tierTwoQuestion t1
left join fetch t.tierThreeQuestion t2